# Should I set this variable to null to save memory?

Tags: php, performance, memory

In my player class written in PHP, I have made it so `$this->forceMove` is null when the player can move, and set to specific coordinates when he cannot.

For example,

```
//Player joins
$this->forceMove = null //Player can move now.
```

Ok, so the player can move now. When he activates a action, to lock his movement I do:

```
$this->forceMove = new Vector3($x, $y, $z); //Player locked in this position.
```

Now for multiple reasons a player can lag out of the game, crash, or lose connection.

Although Garbage Collection will collect data every 30 minutes or less, to improve memory usage I crush a players data (mostly huge arrays) to null.

So my question is, if a player leaves the game while locked, should I reset `$this->forceMove` to null for instant memory back, or let Garbage Collection do it's thing after 30 minutes or so.

I'm looking for the most performance optimized way.